# How to disable scheduled sleep warning in Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: mac, operating-systems, osx-lion, sleep, xorg

I'm creating a kiosk. Would like it to sleep at night and wake in the morning. I know about auto sleep in System Preferences > Energy Saver.

Trouble is, the Mac puts up a dialog box before sleeping saying that the system will sleep in 2 minutes and giving the user a chance to Cancel or Sleep. We don't want that to appear. Any way to disable this warning box?

Answer (score 0):

And, the answer is...

You have to write an AppleScript and then have a program like CronniX trigger it.

Thanks to Dave at the Mac Geek Gab!

Comment: What's the script? Could you tell us what you did to accomplish such a task?